# I am unable to change the permissions of my "Shared Parallels Folder" as it is owned by Root. How do i change this?

Tags: 12.04, gnome-terminal

I would like to change the owner 'root' within in my "Shared Parallels Folder"s properties, so that i will be able to change the permissons of that Shared folder. As I am having problems commanding the gnome terminal to that directory, this could be the reason why. Anyone know how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below command to change the owner of `Shared Parallels Folder` directory from root to `$USER`,

```
sudo chown $USER /path/"Shared Parallels Folder"
```

Comment: The terminal will not recognise the directory, this is my main problem:parallels@parallels-Parallels-Virtual-Platform:~/Desktop$ sudo chown $USER "Shared Parallels Folder"
[sudo] password for parallels: 
chown: cannot access `Shared Parallels Folder': No such file or directory
parallels@parallels-Parallels-Virtual-Platform:~/Desktop$